# Dart Functions and Higher Order Functions

Tags: function, dart, higher-order-functions

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print(duplicate(5));
  print(duplicate2(10));
  print(duplicate3()(20));
  print(duplicate4()(30));
  print(duplicate5()(40));
  print(duplicate8(50));
}

Function duplicate = (int x) {
  return x * 2;
};

//Fat Arrow syntax of duplicate, OK.
Function duplicate2 = (int y) => y * 2;

Function duplicate3() {
  return (int z) => z * 2;
}

Function duplicate4() {
  return duplicate3();
}

Function duplicate5() {
  return duplicate;
}

/*  ERROR, WHY? Same with duplicate4.
Function duplicate6() {
  Function duplicate7() {
    return (int a) => a * 2;
  }
}
*/

//Regular Function
int duplicate8(int a) {
  return a * 2;
}
```

I am trying to learn dart and studying higher functions currently. I have no software background.

I am confused about syntax of function codes above(semicolons, curly braces) and use cases of each functions.

Comment: Can you start by explaining what you think every function does, in detail? We don't know, what you don't know, so we don't know what to explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't use screenshots to post your code unless it is to show some visual errors from your IDE. In all cases, the source code should be posted as text since it makes it easier for us to play around with it and also makes it easier for people with disabilities that makes it hard/impossible to see pictures.

Comment: Also, please post code as text, properly formatted in the editor here as code. Pictures cannot be copy/pasted into the answer, changed, comment on, or even read by screen readers. They cannot be indexed by search engines, so the next person with this question will have to ask again instead of finding an answer. So please post that as text, not as picture.

Comment: Each duplicate function is returning a function. Each of them should do the same thing. I can not understand clearly difference between duplicate and duplicate3 especially.

Comment: `duplicate3` is a function that returns a function (2 layers of function, aka higher order), however `duplicate` is a variable that is assigned a function as its value (1 layer of function, aka first order).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt on describing each of your functions/variables and what they do:

```dart
// Non-final variable with the name `duplicate` that points to a function which
// takes one int value and returns the result of calling *2 on this. 
Function duplicate = (int x) {
  return x * 2;
};

// Same as `duplicate` just using the arrow syntax. So again, a non-final
// variable called `duplicate2` which gets assigned to at function.
Function duplicate2 = (int y) => y * 2;

// A function that returns a Function. The returned function does the same as
// the previous mentioned functions.
Function duplicate3() {
  return (int z) => z * 2;
}

// A function that returns af Function. The returned Function is generated by
// calling the function `duplicate3()` which generates a function that takes an
// int argument and returns the result from doing *2 on it.
Function duplicate4() {
  return duplicate3();
}

// A function that returns the function which is currently assigned to the
// variable `duplicate`.
Function duplicate5() {
  return duplicate;
}
```

For the following:

```dart
/*  ERROR, WHY? Same with duplicate4. */
Function duplicate6() {
  Function duplicate7() {
    return (int a) => a * 2;
  }
}
```

The reason this is not the same as `duplicate4` is because you don't actually return anything from your `duplicate6()` function. Your code should instead have been:

```dart
Function duplicate6() {
  return () {
    return (int a) => a * 2;
  };
}

// OR
Function duplicate6() {
  Function duplicate7() {
    return (int a) => a * 2;
  }

  return duplicate7;
}
```